Windows Batch ERRORLEVEL of ping is not working while in loop
Could anybody help to figure out what the problem is in the following batch code?
I want to check if the device with ip 192.168.0.1 is ready to connect.
I power off the device and power on it after executed the batch.
It seems the %errorlevel% is not working if first check is not 0
@echo off

set "host=192.168.0.1"

for /l %%i in (1,1,255) do (
    ping -n 1 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"
    if %errorlevel% == 0 (
        echo ping %host% ok.
        goto :endLoop
    ) else (
        echo ping %host% fail count %%i
        REM "ping -n 6 -w 1000 " sleep 5 seconds
        ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 -w 1000 > nul
    )
)

:endLoop
echo Done


I got the following log, it can't stop when ping response successfully.
D:\document\code\windows\bat>check_ip.bat
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 1
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 2
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 3
...
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 21
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 22
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 23
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 24
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 2ms
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 25
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 26
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
ping 192.168.0.1 fail count 27
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? Y

I tried the batch on windows 10 machine.
I expect the code can stop after ping response successfully.

First change ping -n 1 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" to %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 "%host%" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "TTL" 1>NUL. Then change the line seven to if not errorlevel 1 (, line ten to ) and remove line fourteen completely. I would also advise that you replace your script's .bat extension with .cmd, as has been correct for tens of years now!

Does this answer your question? Variables are not behaving as expected

Here's my comment as a visual answer. Please note that this is only to show you how to make the ErrorLevel work as intended, (your specific question), not to determine whether a device is ready to connect.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "host=192.168.0.1"

For /L %%G In (1 1 255) Do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 "%host%" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "TTL" 1>NUL 2>&1
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 (
        Echo ping %host% ok.
        GoTo endLoop
    )
    Echo ping %host% fail count %%G
    %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 6 -w 1000 1>NUL
)

:endLoop
Echo Done
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 4 -w 1000 1>NUL
EndLocal

I added the penultimate line just to give you around three seconds to read the Done message. This is only optionally required if you are not running the script from a Command Prompt window.
